# Possible to set default editor for flameshot?

Tags: screenshot

I am running flameshot on Ubuntu 19.10

Is it possible to set the default editor (e.g. **Pinta**) so I don't have to chose that each time I want to edit the screenshot?

E.g when I take a screenshot and click the button below (open in editor)

[image]

I get the following options each time:

[image]

And have to navigate to **Pinta** each time. Seems like it would be an obvious option to be able to configure the default image editor?

Comment: No, without going into the source code and changing this behavior it does not seem to be possible.